# OpenCV cvtColor HSV2RGB assertion

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm having trouble understanding why the following code raises a SIGABRT.

```
cv::Mat someColor(1,1,CV_8UC3);
someColor.at<cv::Scalar>(0,0) = cv::Scalar(100, 100, 100);
cv::cvtColor(someColor, someColor, cv::COLOR_HSV2RGB);
```

Very little debug information is provided. It asserts on cvtColor call.
It should be as simple as creating a 1 pixel HSV matrix, and converting it to RGB colorspace.

Can anyone help?

Comment: CV_8UC3 isnt cv::Scalar but cv::Vec3b

Comment: and post the assertion text ;)

Answer (score 1):

there is a problem on this line

```
someColor.at<cv::Scalar>(0,0) = cv::Scalar(100, 100, 100);
```

you can do it like

```
cv::Mat someColor(1,1,CV_8UC3,cv::Scalar(100, 100, 100));
cv::cvtColor(someColor, someColor, cv::COLOR_HSV2RGB);
cout << someColor;
```

output : [ 61,  87, 100]